# Retrieve a column value without group by statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I need SellerID also in my select statement for them who is having minimum price and maximum price. Below is the query; please tell what change is required??

```
Select count(Id) TotalSeller,
       min(price) as MinPrice, ***SellerID_for_min_price***,
       max(price) as MaxPrice, ***SellerID_for_max_price***
  from ProdPrice
 where prodPriceId=1212
```

Data:

```
ProdId  SellerID    Price
1212    65  34740
1212    20  34855
1212    88  37299
1212    69  38490
1212    108 39990
1212    35  39999
1212    96  40990
```

Comment: There is a whole tag `greatest-n-per-group` for questions like this.  There are a correspondingly large number of answers for similar questions.  The only slightly novel twist in this question is seeking both 'min' and 'max' in the same query, but the techniques will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this sort of query, you want to use `row_number()` to identify the rows with the smallest and largest values:

```
Select count(Id) TotalSeller, min(price) as MinPrice,
       min(case when seqnum_min = 1 then id end) as SellerIdMin,
       max(price),
       min(case when seqnum_max = 1 then id end) as SellerIdMax
from (select pp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by prodPriceId order by price) as seqnum_min,
             row_number() over (partition by prodPriceId order by price desc) as seqnum_max
      from ProdPrice pp
      where prodPriceId=1212
     ) pp
```

To get the names, you can do the join in the subquery:

```
Select count(Id) TotalSeller, min(price) as MinPrice,
       min(case when seqnum_min = 1 then SellerName end) as SellerNameMin,
       max(price),
       min(case when seqnum_max = 1 then SellerName end) as SellerNameMax
from (select pp.*, s.SellerName,
             row_number() over (partition by prodPriceId order by price) as seqnum_min,
             row_number() over (partition by prodPriceId order by price desc) as seqnum_max
      from ProdPrice pp join
           Sellers s
           on pp.id = s.id
      where prodPriceId=1212
     ) pp
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This is what i was looking for. Please do a little more help. I have Sellers Name in another table. how to left outer join to retrieve the both seller name, who have minimum and maximum price

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon.. It's Awesome...Working perfectly for me.